# Reconnecting dropped SqlConnection without rolling back transaction after IP change

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple clients connecting to SQL Server over unreliable (wireless/gprs) network and performing large amounts of small queries and inserts over few minutes. If network connection is broken during the process, whole transaction is rolled back and needs to be restarted. Due to business requirements, process has to be transactional (i.e. other clients see either complete data set from other clients or don't see it at all).

I would like to be able to detect when connection is broken and be able to reconnect to SQL Server and continue process *in the same transaction* that just got dropped and avoid restarting from the beginning. At the moment I use `sp_getbindtoken` right after opening connection, set `CommandTimeout` to small value (much smaller than TCP KeepAlive) and if I get timeout during `ExecuteNonQuery`, I open new connection to server and call `sp_bindsession` with token from the beginning of process. Then I continue process using new connection with session bound to previous process' transaction.

So far it is working almost perfectly, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180061.aspx), this API is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of SQL Server. The question is: how can I achieve same results without those two commands? Is there any other way to resume transaction from dropped TCP connection?

**Edit/further info:** Client application is running on Windows CE devices with barcode scanners. I am providing both devices and software so I'm free to put anything I need there. DB is hosted in protected environment by third party and neither me nor customer has control over it. I have total of ~50MB of daily sales data to send. I can use SP to save data, but it still has to be transmitted and one call to SP with one large argument has close to 0% chance of success over GPRS/EDGE link.

Since the whole solution is working in production environment, I would like to keep changes to minimum. Alternative API with same semantics as `sp_bindsession` would be perfect.

Comment: Have you considered making is a client server application so the TSQL takes place on a server that is hard wired to the SQL server (or is the same device as the SQL server)?

Comment: @BalamBalam: Yes, I created my own class implementing IDbConnection and forwarded all method calls (buffered) to custom server which called appropriate methods on SqlConnection. Tunneling was done using .NET Remoting channels and was robust enough. Unfortunately, now the application is deployed in the environment where I can't place custom code on or near DB server, so I had to use pure TSQL solution.

Comment: Custom code on multiple wireless clients is OK but custom code on single wired box is not OK.  That is kind of strange security logic.  Logical or not it sounds like a hard constraint.  Since a transaction is designed to roll back to the beginning this is going to be problematic at best.  Are you literally running the transaction in .net on the client?  Could you move the  transaction to a stored procedure on the server?

Comment: @BalamBalam: I have just provided further details and reasons for such constraints in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I am just not buying that ~50MB of daily sales data needs to be in a single transaction.  I buy that individual sales-tansactions need need to be wrapped in sql-transaction but those would be more like 1K each.  You sure you cannot run several small transactions on the server in a stored procedure?  If it has to be an all or nothing from each device then load the device to staging table(s) via small transactions.  When the device is done then use a stored procedure on the server in a transactions to flush the staging tables.  Or just put a boolean column on the upload of complete then flip that flag in a single update when the upload is complete.  A 50MB transaction would really hammer a the transaction log and lock out other updates.

Comment: "Sales data" include payment plans, details, agreements, annexes, document scans - it's usually a lot more than 50MB a day and with `read committed snapshot` isolation it's working pretty good whether you buy it or not. Sending data on the fly in small transactions is feasible, but wasn't when system was deployed. Rewriting application's guts won't get approved any time soon. I asked about obsolete API and not design tips because I'm stuck with it for good. Thanks for your feedback, though. I'll opt for staging tables should `sp_bindsession` be removed in next version of SQL Server.

Comment: I am not doubting it is 50MB in a day.  What I am doubting is that is one transaction.  The purpose of a transaction is to have row level data in multiple tables in a consistent state.  Are you sure you cannot break that 50MB down into multiple atomic transactions?

Comment: It could be broken down into smaller chunks, but to be honest I was looking for an answer like "use this SP instead" or "this API is removed because of (...) and you'll have to change your application". I agree transactions are not meant to be used this way but I don't have authority to enforce changes in that piece of code, no matter how bad it is.

Comment: Cool, but the nature of a transaction is to hold the whole transaction in limbo and then either commit or roll it back.  Holding 50 MB in limbo is just big burden and seriously doubt there is magic fix other than break it down to the true ATOMIC nature.   A 50 MB transaction over a reliable connection is going to be problematic - if you have to do it over an unreliable connection then my condolences.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN link you provided suggests using [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  According to the article:

> MARS allows a connection to be used for both read operations and data manipulation language (DML) operations with more than one pending operation. This feature eliminates the need for an application to deal with connection-busy errors. In addition, MARS can replace the user of server-side cursors, which generally consume more resources. Finally, because multiple operations can operate on a single connection, they can share the same transaction context, eliminating the need to use sp_getbindtoken and sp_bindsession system stored procedures.

This way you can use BeginTrasaction and the transaction will be automatically rolled back unless you explicitly commit it.  You can catch the failure of the commit statement and recursively try to resubmit it until the commit of the transaction returns successfully.  Just an idea.  Maybe something like this:

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            //Both records are written to database.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
                ExecuteSqlTransaction(connectionString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Failure can happen not only on commit, but on every other statement. E.g. if there were three calls to `ExecuteNonQuery` and 2nd call failed, I'd like to continue execution with 2nd call - you suggested restarting it all over from 1st statement.